# I get a FormatException when I'm trying to parse a Double

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I am working on a Windows 8 Application. I have a listbox that shows specicic things for an item that  is clicked on(SelectedIndex).

Based on the text that is shown in the different textboxes i create a new instance for a class that takes the information and puts then in an object. From that object i put the different objectinformation into double variables that I can output in the screen with the "toString()" method. Each time I wanna "add" something to the list i want the numbers to multiply instead of that the text strings just adds to eachother for example:

```
 totalWeight += double.Parse(tbx_TotalVikt.Text);
```

Here I want the totalWeight(wich is a double) to be a parsed version of the text that is in the tbx_TotalVikt.Text. But I keep getting this error message:

An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: what was the input you tried to parse?

Comment: I have a "double weight;" that I want to add to whenever i Add to the textboxs text. I am trying to parse the value that is in the tbx_TotalVikt.Text to a double so that I can add to the value, now it just adds as a string and the code above gives me a error message..

Comment: "double weight;" is definitely not a number. martennis is trying to establish the **value** of `tbx_TotalVikt.Text` at the time `Parse` is called.

Comment: The values is a number for example: 355. Im trying to parse a number that is a string when in a textbox.text.

Comment: In debug mode, what does tbx_TotalVikt.Text have for value? Maybe it doesn't have the value you expect?

Comment: Its the correct. "100" is in the tbx_TotalVikt.Text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.

```
double item = 0;
if(double.TryParse(tbx_TotalVikt.Text, out item))
            {
                totalWeight += item;
            }
tbx_TotalVikt.Text = totalWeight.ToString();
```

Used TryParse to look if the text is a double.

Answer (score 2):

It's best practice to provide a format provider as a second parameter when parsing numbers.

```
double.Parse("1.254", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat)
```

If you are sure that this is not the problem, then you are supplying garbage to the `Parse` method, and should investigate your input in the debugger.